# Get last inserted Id returns 0 if the row already exists

Tags: c#, mysql

When I use:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE INTO users (Name, ...) VALUES ('user1',..) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastSeen=NOW();
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
COMMIT;
```

When i run this query from my sql client I get the last inserted id as expected.

But what if the user already exists?(table uniquness). So no new id is created. But now when I run the same query from my sql client still i get the `id` as expected.

But! when I run it from my `C#` code and use `mysql.reader` to query the result I receive `0`. Why is that??

If instead of `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` I use `SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` I get the right id again.

**EDIT!**

This is not a duplicate of the suggested topic. In that topic the answer says that the auto-incremented is not the primary key, thats not my case! also as I mark it does return the right id when i use the mysql client! The problem occures only when I run it from my c# code!

My C# code:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        var command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = strSQL;
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
                result = reader[0].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new MySqlException("SQL Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
        reader.Close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: LAST\_INSERT\_ID() returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880267/mysql-last-insert-id-returns-0)

Comment: @adv12 not a duplicate, read my edit

Comment: probably when you `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` **UPDATE** the record mysql does not return **LAST_INSERT_ID** because it was not inserted.

Comment: and post your c# code. some people here are smart enough to read c# :-)

Comment: @Alex you guys dont read my question fully. It does return the right id when i run the sql as is! The problem is only from my c# code

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/5228819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work around, simple `CASE` clause does the job:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE INTO users (Name, ...) VALUES ('user1',..) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastSeen=NOW();
SELECT CASE WHEN LAST_INSERT_ID()=0 THEN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE Name = 'user1') ELSE LAST_INSERT_ID() END;
COMMIT;
```

Now in case the user exists, we simply query the id, If it doest not exists, the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give us the right id

Answer (score 1):

From what I read there https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057619/4421474

Your code could be transformed to:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
   conn.Open();
   var command = conn.CreateCommand();
   command.CommandText = strSQL; <--  just insert part like "START ... INSERT ... COMMIT;"
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   string result = command.LastInsertedId;
   return result;
}
```

Sorry I am not c# expert so some syntax could be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer:

> Just my 50 cents for this issue, I simply noticed that you won't get a LAST_INSERT_ID greater than 0 if your table has no AUTO_INCREMENT set to an index

that i found here [MySQL: LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880267/mysql-last-insert-id-returns-0) is the good one.