# js Slideshow from MySQL Database not looping through images

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net

I have js slideshow that shows images from a mysql database. The problem Im having is its only showing the first image in the table for each foreign key when there are multiple images with the same foreign key.

The property table containing all the information, PropertyID is the primary key.
The propertyimage table contains the image name and path as well as PropertyID as the foreign key.
https://imgur.com/gallery/Ipdfw

In this screenshot you can see the slideshow but just loops through only showing the first image.
https://imgur.com/gallery/S1H2g

This is the slideshow im using I like Robots jquery slideshow.

c#

```
protected void GetImages2()
{
    foreach (DataListItem item in DataList1.Items)
    {
        Repeater Repeater2 = ((Repeater)(item.FindControl("Repeater2")));
        Label Label8 = ((Label)(item.FindControl("Label8")));

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["realestatedbAddConString"].ConnectionString;

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM propertyimage WHERE PropertyID = '" + Label8.Text + "'", con))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    Repeater2.DataSource = dt;

                    try {
                        Repeater2.DataBind();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
                    }

                    con.Close();

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

the repeater with the slideshow is inside a datalist.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <br />
            <h2 class="text-center">PROPERTY ID</h2>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("PropertyID") %>' runat="server" ID="Label8" Style="margin-left: 50%; font-size: x-large; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: silver;" class="text-center" />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help to fixing this would be greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Edit*
slideshow source from inspect element in browser

```
<div class="slideshow" data-transition="crossfade" data-loop="true" data-skip="false" data-pagination="true">
    <div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;">
        <ul class="carousel">           
        <li class="slide" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
            <img src="ImagesUploaded/fire%20chape.jpg" style="height:526px;width:950px;">
        </li>   
        <li class="slide" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
            <img src="ImagesUploaded/ghost%20recon.png" style="height:526px;width:950px;">
        </li>   
        <li class="slide" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;">
            <img src="ImagesUploaded/Ghost-Rider-Wallpaper-photo.jpeg" style="height:526px;width:950px;">
        </li>   
        <li class="slide" style="">
            <img src="ImagesUploaded/goat-skull.jpg" style="height:526px;width:950px;">
        </li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
<ul class="slides-pagination"><li class=""><a href="#" data-slides="0">1</a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-slides="1">2</a></li><li class=""><a href="#" data-slides="2">3</a></li><li class="selected"><a href="#" data-slides="3">4</a></li></ul></div>
```

slideshow js:

```
! function (a, b) {
    "use strict";

    function c(b, c) {
        return this.target = b, this.$target = a(b), this.opts = a.extend({}, d, c, this.$target.data()), this.$carousel = this.$target.children(this.opts.carousel), this.$items = this.$carousel.children(this.opts.items), this.count = this.$items.length, this.scrollable = !0, this.count > 1 && this._init(), this
    }
    var d = {
        carousel: ".carousel",
        items: ".slide",
        slideWidth: !1,
        jumpQueue: !0,
        offset: 1,
        skip: !0,
        pagination: !0,
        auto: 6e3,
        autostop: !0,
        hoverPause: !1,
        loop: !1,
        nextText: "Next",
        previousText: "Previous",
        transition: "scroll",
        speed: 600,
        easing: "swing",
        visible: 1,
        onupdate: null,
        oncomplete: null
    };
    c.prototype._init = function () {
        var b = this;
        if (this.$wrapper = this.$carousel.wrap('<div style="position:relative;overflow:hidden;">').parent(), this.opts.pagination) {
            this.$pagination = a('<ul class="slides-pagination">');
            for (var c = 0, d = this.count; d > c; c++) this.$pagination.append('<li><a href="#" data-slides="' + c + '">' + (c + 1) + "</a></li>");
            this.$target.append(this.$pagination)
        }
        this.opts.skip && (this.$prev = a('<a href="#" class="slides-prev" data-slides="previous">' + this.opts.previousText + "</a>"), this.$next = a('<a href="#" class="slides-next" data-slides="next">' + this.opts.nextText + "</a>"), this.$target.append(this.$next, this.$prev)), (this.opts.pagination || this.opts.skip) && this.$target.on("click.slides", "[data-slides]", function (c) {
            var d = a(this);
            c.preventDefault(), d.hasClass("disabled") || b.to(d.data("slides"), !0)
        }), this.redraw(), this.opts.auto && (this.opts.hoverPause && this.$target.hover(function () {
            b.stopped || b.pause()
        }, function () {
            b.paused && b.play()
        }), this.play())
    }, c.prototype._oncomplete = function () {
        var a = this.current;
        this.current = this.future, this.opts.pagination && this.$pagination.children().removeClass("selected").slice(this.current, this.current + this.opts.visible).addClass("selected"), this.opts.skip && (this.hasNext() || this.opts.loop ? this.$next.removeClass("disabled") : this.$next.addClass("disabled"), this.hasPrevious() || this.opts.loop ? this.$prev.removeClass("disabled") : this.$prev.addClass("disabled")), this.opts.oncomplete && this._handleCallback(this.opts.oncomplete, [this.current, a])
    }, c.prototype._handleCallback = function (a, b) {
        a = "string" == typeof a ? window[a] : a, a.call && a.apply(this, b)
    }, c.prototype.hasNext = function () {
        return this.scrollable && this.current < this.count - 1
    }, c.prototype.hasPrevious = function () {
        return this.current > 0
    }, c.prototype.next = function () {
        this.to(this.current + 1)
    }, c.prototype.previous = function () {
        this.to(this.current - 1)
    }, c.prototype.to = function (a, b) {
        if (this.opts.jumpQueue) this.$items.stop(!0, !0);
        else if (this.$items.queue("fx").length) return;
        "next" === a ? a = this.current + 1 : "previous" === a && (a = this.current - 1), "number" != typeof a && (a = parseInt(a, 10)), a >= this.count ? a = this.opts.loop ? 0 : this.count - 1 : 0 > a && (a = this.opts.loop ? this.count - 1 : 0), b && !this.stopped && (this.opts.autostop ? this.stop() : this.paused || this.play()), a !== this.current && (this.future = a, this.transition.execute.call(this), this.opts.onupdate && this._handleCallback(this.opts.onupdate, [a]))
    }, c.prototype.redraw = function (a) {
        this.transition && this.transition.teardown.call(this), a && (this.opts.transition = a), this.current = b, this.transition = this.transitions[this.opts.transition].call(this), this.to(this.opts.offset - 1)
    }, c.prototype.play = function () {
        var a = this;
        clearInterval(this.timeout), this.paused = this.stopped = !1, this.timeout = setInterval(function () {
            a.to("next")
        }, this.opts.auto)
    }, c.prototype.pause = function () {
        this.paused = !0, clearInterval(this.timeout)
    }, c.prototype.stop = function () {
        this.stopped = !0, this.paused = !1, clearInterval(this.timeout)
    }, c.prototype.transitions = {
        crossfade: function () {
            var a = this;
            return this.$items.filter(function (b) {
                return b !== a.opts.offset - 1
            }).css("display", "none"), this.execute = function () {
                var b = this.$items.eq(this.future),
                    c = this.$items.eq(this.current).css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        left: 0,
                        top: 0
                    });
                b.fadeIn(this.opts.speed, this.opts.easing, function () {
                    a._oncomplete.call(a)
                }), c.fadeOut(this.opts.speed, this.opts.easing, function () {
                    c.css("position", "")
                })
            }, this.teardown = function () {
                this.$items.stop(!0, !0).removeAttr("style")
            }, this
        },
        scroll: function () {
            var a = this,
                b = 0;
            this.$items.css({
                "float": "left",
                width: this.opts.slideWidth
            });
            for (var c = 0; c < this.count; c++) b += this.$items.eq(c).outerWidth(!0);
            return this.$carousel.css({
                minWidth: b
            }), this.execute = function () {
                var b = this.$items.eq(this.future).position().left + this.$wrapper.scrollLeft(),
                    c = this.$carousel.width() - this.$wrapper.width(),
                    d = b >= c;
                (!d || this.scrollable) && this.$wrapper.animate({
                    scrollLeft: d ? c : b
                }, this.opts.speed, this.opts.easing, function () {
                    a._oncomplete.call(a)
                }), this.scrollable = !d
            }, this.teardown = function () {
                this.scrollable = !0, this.$items.removeAttr("style"), this.$carousel.stop(!0, !0).removeAttr("style")
            }, this
        }
    }, a.fn.slides = function (b) {
        return this.each(function () {
            a.data(this, "slides") || a.data(this, "slides", new c(this, b))
        })
    }, "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(function () {
        return c
    }) : "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && (module.exports = c)
}(jQuery);




<script src="2/dist/slideshow.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Create slideshow instances
            var $s = $('.slideshow').slides();

            // Access an instance API
            var api = $s.eq(0).data('slides');

            // Transition select
            $('select[name=transition]').on('change', function () {
                api.redraw(this.value);
            });



        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide your JQuery script in the question? Also place a breakpoint on the dt object so that we can see whats actually returned from your query

Comment: Please load the page in a web browser, view source and include the source (the resulting source, not your source code) in the post as well.

Comment: Looks like there could be a problem in one of two places 1) Your SQL query isnt returning what you think it is 2) Your jQuery script isnt correct, either way you need to provide more information before anyone can accurately help,

Comment: @MasterYoda edit shows script.

Comment: @mjwills output from console in edit

Comment: @Aaron177 Thanks for that, from the source you posted it looks like your sql query is fine and the dt object is populated as expected. Most likely the issue is with your JQuery script. Ill take a look now

Comment: @MasterYoda any luck?

Comment: @Aaron177 see my answer, let me know how you get on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the code you are using:

```
// Create slideshow instances
var $s = $('.slideshow').slides();

// Access an instance API
var api = $s.eq(0).data('slides');

// Transition select
$('select[name=transition]').on('change', function () {
      api.redraw(this.value);
 });
```

especially the line: `var api = $s.eq(0).data('slides');` selects only the first image in the array and redraws it each time on a loop.

The I like Robots JQuery Slideshow documentation found [here](http://i-like-robots.github.io/jQuery-Slideshow/) gives the following example for initialising the plugin:

```
// Create slideshow instances
var $slideshow = $('.slideshow').slides(),

// Access an instance API
api = $slideshow.data('slides');
```

Give this a try by replacing whats in your script with the code above.

Comment: i think how im adding the multiple images to the database is the problem https://imgur.com/gallery/a8lyH just noticed this. Thanks for all your help though!

Comment: @Aaron177 Can you expand on that? im guessing (going by your first image) that you save the local path to the images in the DB rather than saving the images themselves as bytes?

Comment: yeah i saved the image paths, as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012459/how-to-insert-multiple-images-into-mysql-database-table-with-foreign-key-referen