# MySQL trigger + insert

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm trying to get my current id from a table pk to insert on another table fk, my next try is set a trigger inside database.

```sql
    CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERIR CODIGO DISPENSACAO` ()
    CREATE TRIGGER `productInsert`
        BEFORE INSERT ON `produtos_disp`
        FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    set NEW.ID_PRODISP = (select max(ID)
                        from dispensacao p            
                       );
    END
```

what I want to set max id from dispensacao table which is going to be inserted from auto_increment on insert to it, on my fk codigo_disp for every row.

Comment: that will not realy work, as multiple connections could increase the id and you would have the wrong id. you should run the first, get the last_inserted_id, aned then the next in c#

Comment: Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Also don't you want `AFTER INSERT`?

Comment: here is an example for last_insert_id https://stackoverflow.com/a/15057619/5193536

Comment: isnt last inserted id usable only with the same connection

Comment: can you explain to me how it will get the last inserted id from a table that is not even mentioned on that example, how will it knows wich id  to use

Comment: to clarify, what i doing is a delivery control app, so, someone call for a delivery(dispensacao table hold the info, who asked for(solicitante) who attended(deferido_por) date... but a person can ask for multiples itens and i need to insert on produtos_disp all products that belongs to its delivery, it's 1 delevery wich is 1 id to many products

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE `INSERIR CODIGO DISPENSACAO` ()
CREATE TRIGGER `productInsert`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `produtos_disp`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
set NEW.ID_PRODISP = (select max(ID)
                    from dispensacao p            
                   );
END something like that i guess

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get max id using a combobox as descending order.
used

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("connectionString");

        string selectQuery = "select ID from dispensacao ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        connection.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2.Load(reader);           
        Cmbid.DisplayMember = "ID";            
       Cmbid.DataSource = dt2;
```

this return the max id from the table and all you need to do is make it invisible so user won't change as it is a combobox